# Unable to run executable with '.Move' in filename as non-admin

Tags: windows-10

I had a C# winforms project that had ".Move" in the name. Whenever we ran it in Visual Studio, we got an 'Access is denied' error.

After trying different things, we noticed that it only happens when the executable filename has '.Move' in it. However, if we ran that executable as administrator, it'd run without any problem. I've tried renaming other '.exe' files on my computer with the same result.

[image: You may not have the appropriate permissions to access the item.]

Does anyone know why you can't run an executable with `.Move` in it as non-admin user in Windows 10?

To reproduce, simply rename an executable to include '.Move' in the name and try to run it under an non-administrator account.

Comment: Is this computer managed by an organization (Active Directory) or is it your own?

Comment: Yes, it's managed by an organization. If it doesn't happen for others, I'd assume maybe it'd be some policy/software deployed by my organization?

Comment: So it's not reproducible. Windows don't care if `.move` is in its name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no built-in restriction in Windows itself for programs named like this. Your organization has almost certainly deployed a "Software Restrictions" Group Policy with overly-broad or poorly-chosen rules.

You need to check with IT management in your organization to see if they can tell you what the rules are that they use to block execution.

Depending on how the policy was deployed, it might be possible to see what the policy is on your computer if you have administrator privileges. To do that, run `gpedit.msc` to open the Local Group Policy editor, then go to "Computer Configuration" -> "Windows Settings" -> "Security Settings" -> "Software Restriction Policies".

Alternatively, if you have access to one of your Active Directory servers (or to a sympathetic IT person), you can find the policy using the Group Policy Management tool on the server.

Comment: Or type `gpresult /r /z` to test your theory.